# Error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator^'

Tags: c++, operands

I'm getting the error invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator^' and I'm not sure how to fix it

The error occurs in the function f, in the last line

Any help is much appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;
float f(float x);

int main()
{

    float a;
    float b;
    int n;
    float h;
    float x;
    float area;

    cout << "Please input the first limit: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please input the second limit: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many rectangles do you want to use? ";
    cin >> n;

    h = (b-a)/n;

    area = (f(a)+f(b))/2;

    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        area += f(a+i*h);
    }

    area = area*h;
    cout << "The area under the curve of f(x) = (2/sqrt(3.14))(exp(-x^2)) is ";
    cout << area;
}

float f(float x){
     return (exp(-x^2))(2/sqrt(3.14));
}
```

Comment: `exp(-x^2)` does not do what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` has the data type `float`. You have applied the logical XOR operator to it. XOR requires integer operands.

I suspect you're looking for an exponent, though. C++ has no exponent operator. Instead, try something like this:

```
float f(float x){
     return (exp(-(x*x)))*(2/sqrt(3.14));
}
```

I assume that you mean to multiply `exp(-(x*x))` by `(2/sqrt(3.14)`, but I didn't see a multiplication operator there.

Comment: Clarification: '^' is the XOR operator, not an exponentiation operator.

Comment: Worth to mention `pow`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Good point. `pow(x, n)` will return *x* to the *n*th power. Personally, I never use `pow()` for squares, but I agree that it's good to be aware of it.

Comment: Isn't _-x^2_ usually _-x*-x_?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet It would be pointless to include a minus sign if the intention was to square *-x*, since the square of a negative is identical to the square of a positive. Therefore, it seemed that the author's intent was to take the negative of the square.

Comment: @Logicrat: How do you know _-x_ is a negative?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I don't. But I do know that `(x)*(x)` yields the same result as `(-x)*(-x)`, and I do know that that result is a positive value.