# Error Message : Invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide, decimal-point

**Environment:** Arduino IDE (v1.8.13)

In one of my project i am trying to display decimal temperature value (temp) using float data type this code works properly for int data type. Could any one help me to solve this error "Invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'". I am beginner in programming

As reference, i did this troubleshooting [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209026/error-invalid-operands-of-types-float-and-int-to-binary-operator) and [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209026/error-invalid-operands-of-types-float-and-int-to-binary-operator)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209026/error-invalid-operands-of-types-float-and-int-to-binary-operator): [Float Data Type in Switch Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897370/float-data-type-in-switch-statement) but could not found specific solution.

Thank You in Advance !

Full Program :

```
  switch (current_digit)
  {
   case 1:
    disp((temp / 100) % 10);
    digitalWrite(Dig1, LOW);  // turn on digit 1
  break;

case 2:
  disp( (temp / 10) % 10);   // prepare to display digit 2
  digitalWrite(SegDP, LOW);  // print decimal point ( . )
  digitalWrite(Dig2, LOW);   // turn on digit 2
  break;

case 3:
  disp(temp % 10);   // prepare to display digit 3
  digitalWrite(Dig3, LOW);    // turn on digit 3
}

current_digit = (current_digit % 3) + 1;
}

  }
```

Comment: Try using the [fmod()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod) function instead of the `%` operator. (Or rather, the `fmodf()` function if you're using `float` variables.)

Comment: no need to post 200 lines of code if your questin is about a simple error for applying an operator to the wrong types.  please do your own web research befor posting a question. especially for trivial things like this  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MathHeader  and please refer to the manual https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/arithmetic-operators/remainder/  here you find: allowed datatype: Int, ... warning the remainder operator does not work on floats!

Comment: You shouln't be using floating point on Arduino anyhow, because it's a horribly slow 8 bitter without FPU. If you actually need floating point, which isn't the case in this example, you picked the wrong MCU for the task.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated `%` is for integer types.

To get the first decimal place round your value and subtract that rounded number from your value. Muliply the difference by 10. You get rid of the decimals by either using the floor funciton or by casting to integer.

Simplified example:

```
12.5... -> 12
12.5... - 12 -> 0.5...
0.5... * 10 -> 5.00...
5.0... -> 5
```

Alternatively convert your value to a char array. This will allow you to access each digit conveniently.
Change your display functions so they will take char values.